# É possível integrar o SVN com minha ferramenta de controle de tarefas?

Tags: delphi, svn

Possuo um ambiente de desenvolvimento com um servidor de SVN rodando com o VisualSVN e terminais com o TortoiseSVN. Neste mesmo ambiente possuo um sistema de controle de tarefas, feito em Delphi, no qual as tarefas são atribuídas aos desenvolvedores.

Uma vez que uma tarefa esteja sendo executada é necessário que o desenvolvedor encarregado da mesma forneça detalhes sobre o andamento do processo. O problema ao meu ver é que isto acaba gerando uma certa redundância no processo realizado por parte do desenvolvedor, uma vez que ao efetuar os commits no SVN o mesmo já escreve no log o processo que foi realizado com aquela cópia de trabalho.

Tendo isto em mente o meu objetivo seria de fazer com que ao escrever o log na tela de commit do SVN, aquele texto do log já fosse inserido na minha base de dados vinculada a aquela respectiva tarefa no nosso sistema de controle de tarefas. Pelo que pesquisei é praticamente consenso que este processo deveria ser realizado por script no evento post-commit do SVN.

Um problema com esse fato é que os tratamentos desse evento, pelo que vi, devem ser feitos em Shell-Script, mas no entanto não entendo de Shell Script e nem uso Linux (Pois desenvolvemos com Delphi). Alguém que trabalhe com Delphi já conseguiu realizar este tipo de integração? Caso fosse possível eu poderia pegar os dados da tarefa no próprio nome do *branch* utilizando Regex, mas estou sem ideias de por onde começar, apreciaria sugestões.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que encontrei em [alguns](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/11/10/an-introduction-to-subversion-hook-scripts-on-windows/) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633614/svn-hooks-for-windows) o *hook* de *post-commit* do SVN num ambiente Windows pode facilmente ser direcionado para um arquibo *batch* (`.bat`).

O repositório e o identificador do *commit* são recebidos por parâmetros no script e podem ser acessados assim:

```batch
set REPOS=%1  
set TXN=%2
```

O comentário do commit pode ser obtido executando o `svnlook`. Achei um exemplo que suporta até comentários com quebras de linhas [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381572/getting-log-message-from-svnlook-via-windows-batch). Veja o código:

```batch
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LF=^


rem ** The two empty lines are NECESSARY

SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2

SET MSG=
FOR /F %%i in ('svnlook log -r %REV% %REPOS%') do (
    SET "VAR=!VAR!!LF!%%i"
    SET "PAR=!PAR!^^!LF!!LF!%%i"
)
ECHO !VAR!
myProgram.exe !par!
```

Note que, ao final, o código acima executa `myProgram.exe`. Este poderia ser substituído por um executável seu que interpreta o comentário e insere as informações necessárias em sua base de dados.

Comment: Vou analisar sua resposta agora mesmo e verificar se é de fato o que preciso. Obrigado.